# Magento - Function calling on an Event trigger

Tags: events, function, magento, triggers, observer-pattern

i want to call a function when a customer signs in. For that i need to create a function when an event is triggered ,here in my case event should be "customer_login".
Can anyone please help me by providing some sample.
i have came across so many tutorials .As i am a newbie am quite unaware of magento file structure .please help

Answer (score 4):

Please see [Customize Magento using Event/Observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method). Especially the example steps 3, 4 & 5 which explain the files to create.